# what is an alternative to exit(); without breaking page

Tags: php, upload, exit-code

For example, now when I kill a script using `die()` or `exit()` my pages look half broken because the bottom part of the page's html failed to load since it was being brought in using the `include()` function.

So is there a way to tell PHP "don't allow any more commands to be executed except the rest of the webpage loading" ?

I am using this for an image upload script.

front: [image]

but when I have a wrong file type uploaded or no file at all, it breaks my webpage because I set exit();

[image]
[image]

What can I do to fix this? Here is my code and you'll notice the exit();'s

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_uniq_id = uniqid();

    // Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
    // and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information

    $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
    $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension

    // START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------

    if (!$fileTmpLoc)
    { // if file not chosen
        echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
        exit();
    }
    else
    if ($fileSize > 5242880)
    { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
        echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        exit();
    }
    else
    if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName))
    {

        // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types

        echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        exit();
    }
    else
    if ($fileErrorMsg == 1)
    { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
        echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
        exit();
    }

    // END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ----------------------------------------------------
    // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function

    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");

    // Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing

    if ($moveResult != true)
    {
        echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        exit();
    }

    // unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    // ---------- Include Adams Universal Image Resizing Function --------

    include_once ("libs/ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php");

    $target_file = "uploads/$fileName";
    $resized_file = "uploads/" . $file_uniq_id . "." . $fileExt;
    $resized_file_final = $file_uniq_id . "." . $fileExt;
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image = '$resized_file_final' WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $wmax = 128;
    $hmax = 128;
    ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
    unlink($target_file);

    // ----------- End Adams Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
    // Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes

    echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
    echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
    echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
    echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
    echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: <strong>$fileErrorMsg</strong><br /><br />";
    echo "The new name for the file is: <strong>$resized_file_final</strong>";
}
```

Comment: Don't echo inside functions. Seperate your business logic from your presentation layer (html)

Comment: @Fred -ii- what does that mean...?

Comment: @BrianCherdak What you mean? I think you may have seen a comment I made in regards to my comment to Rakesh; no worries, all is fine. Now, you can try and use `return;` see if that works for you, not 100% sure it will work, but try it.

Comment: I am still having issues, I tried the break(); @matthew5025

Comment: Dont ask PHP to compensate for bad coding. Dont echo the error messages, place them in a variable. Then at the bottom of the code where you do all the clever stuff with the image, put a test of the error message variable, if there is an error just output the error, otherwise do the clever stuff and output the image info

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i set the variable as `$error = "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";` and outputting it lower in my script as `<?php echo $error; ?>` but it still seems to load half the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the idea is you have to complete the whole script so you get to add the page footer so the page looks complete. So instead of echoing errors as you find them AND THEN EXITing the script, save them in a variable. Then once you get to the main part of the script i.e. the image is loaded and you want to resize it, you decide if you had an error to output only the error and not do the image resize. If no errors are found then you fiddle with the image and dont output any error messages.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_uniq_id = uniqid();

    // Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
    // and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information

    $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
    $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension

    // START PHP Image Upload Error Handling 

    $Err = NULL;

    if (!$fileTmpLoc)
    { // if file not chosen
        $Err = "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    }
    else
    if ($fileSize > 5242880)
    { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
        $Err = "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    }
    else
    if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName))
    {
        // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types

        $Err = "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    }
    else
    if ($fileErrorMsg == 1)
    { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
        $Err = "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
    }

    // END PHP Image Upload Error Handling 
    // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function

    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");

    // Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing

    if ($moveResult != true) {
        $Err = "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
        // not needed PHP is supposed to do this
        // unlink($fileTmpLoc);
    }

    // ---------- Include Adams Universal Image Resizing Function --------

    if ( ! isset( $Err ) ) {    

        include_once ("libs/ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php");

        $target_file = "uploads/$fileName";
        $resized_file = "uploads/" . $file_uniq_id . "." . $fileExt;
        $resized_file_final = $file_uniq_id . "." . $fileExt;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                     SET profile_image = '$resized_file_final' 
                     WHERE id = '$id' ");
        $wmax = 128;
        $hmax = 128;
        ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
        unlink($target_file);

        // ----------- End Adams Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
        // Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes

        // as we had to process error in this if we better test again
        echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
        echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
        echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
        echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
        echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: <strong>$fileErrorMsg</strong><br /><br />";
        echo "The new name for the file is: <strong>$resized_file_final</strong>";

    } else {
       echo $Err;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `function`s are used to group code together. Then you can stop a function half-way with a `return;` statement. Functions keep code organized and reusable. Next step would be to put related functions in classes and then to separate code that generates output (echo-statements) and logic into different classes, but this is a while new paradigm for you to grasp (look into object-orientated programming - OOP. It's hard, but it's really important if you want to advance).

As an example of grouping your code into functions the code in your if-statement can be put in an uploadFile-function, like so:

```
<?php

function uploadFile($id, $file) {
    $file_uniq_id = uniqid();

    // Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
    // and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information

    $fileName = $file["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $file["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $file["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $file["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $file["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
    $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension

    // START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------

    if (!$fileTmpLoc)
    { // if file not chosen
        echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
        return;
    }
    else
    if ($fileSize > 5242880)
    { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
        echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        return;
    }
    else
    if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName))
    {

        // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types

        echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        return;
    }
    else
    if ($fileErrorMsg == 1)
    { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
        echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
        return;
    }

    // END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ----------------------------------------------------
    // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function

    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");

    // Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing

    if ($moveResult != true)
    {
        echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        return;
    }

    // unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    // ---------- Include Adams Universal Image Resizing Function --------

    include_once ("libs/ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php");

    $target_file = "uploads/$fileName";
    $resized_file = "uploads/" . $file_uniq_id . "." . $fileExt;
    $resized_file_final = $file_uniq_id . "." . $fileExt;
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image = '$resized_file_final' WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $wmax = 128;
    $hmax = 128;
    ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
    unlink($target_file);

    // ----------- End Adams Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
    // Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes

    echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
    echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
    echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
    echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
    echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: <strong>$fileErrorMsg</strong><br /><br />";
    echo "The new name for the file is: <strong>$resized_file_final</strong>";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    uploadFile($id, $_FILES["uploaded_file"]);
}
```

While this is still far from well organized code, it solves your problem by replacing `exit()` with `return;`.

Comment: This seemed to work perfect, but a small error that a variable isnt set **$id**
but it is, above 
`$id   = $_GET['id'];
     $id   = stripslashes($id);
        $id   = mysql_real_escape_string($id); 
  
// GET id is set and not empty and is numeric
if (isset($id) && !empty($id) && is_numeric($id)) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
// Else take value from session, if not empty and is numeric
elseif (isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_SESSION['id']);
}`

Comment: See updated version. I added $id as a parameter to the function and pass the original $id you've set in the code further above in the function call.

Comment: thanks, one more small thing, I set it so only certain types of files can be uploaded, but when I try to upload a pdf file, WHICH IS NOT allowed, it trys to process it through and gives me warning errors `Warning: move_uploaded_file(/tmp/phpSsaO6r) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u315295673/public_html/new/profile_pic.php on line 285

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpSsaO6r' to 'uploads/pics.pdf' in /home/u315295673/public_html/new/profile_pic.php on line 285`

Comment: I thought I have if statements in place to automatically show an error if its not a gif,png, or jpg., how is it getting by them?

Comment: I tried changing it to this `if (($fileName == "image/gif") || ($fileName == "image/jpeg") || ($fileName == "image/png" )) {` from `if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName)) {` but now it seems to allow any files.